# Localhost is not working but site is working in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am learning Android.  And i am trying to read the PHP output (through JSON ) from Android.

If i give the Site URL, its fetching the value.  If you enter the site it display the Json code like below.

http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php";

{"emp_info":[{"employee name":"Adam","employee no":"101700"},{"employee name":"John","employee no":"101701"},{"employee name":"Paul","employee no":"101702"},{"employee name":"Mark","employee no":"101703"},{"employee name":"Donald","employee no":"101704"},{"employee name":"Brain","employee no":"101705"},{"employee name":"Kevin","employee no":"101706"}]}

If i give my local host PHP site also it displaying like above in the format of Json. ( I am running PHP using WAMPSERVER)

{"emp_info":[{"employee name":"Adam","employee no":"101700"},{"employee name":"John","employee no":"101701"},{"employee name":"Paul","employee no":"101702"},{"employee name":"Mark","employee no":"101703"},{"employee name":"Donald","employee no":"101704"},{"employee name":"Brain","employee no":"101705"},{"employee name":"Kevin","employee no":"101706"}]}

But in the Android it displaying results if i give the site, but if i give localhost address it says application stopped unexpectedly.

Please let me know why??. In this case how i can see the errors OR exceptions.

I provided the PHP and Android code below.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$host=""; //replace with database
$username="root"; //replace with database username 
$password="root"; //replace with database password 
$db_name="and"; //replace with database name

$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from emp_info"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json['emp_info'][]=$row;
}
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

Android Java code:

In the below code in the URL i changed to localhost URL

package com.example.phpmysql;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private String jsonResult;
 Private String url = "http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php";

 private ListView listView;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  accessWebService();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 // Async Task to access the web
 private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
   try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
      response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
   }

   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
   String rLine = "";
   StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

   try {
    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     answer.append(rLine);
    }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   return answer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   ListDrwaer();
  }
 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
  JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
  // passes values for the urls string array
  task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
  List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("employee name");
    String number = jsonChildNode.optString("employee no");
    String outPut = name + "-" + number;
    employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
   }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
 }

 private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
  HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
  employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
  return employeeNameNo;
 }
}
```

Comment: How you enter `localhost` `URL` ? And are you using mobile OR emulator ?

Comment: I am using Emulator.  Yes i gave http://localhost/PHPMYSQL/index.php in the place or URL

Answer (score 1):

when localhost worked i'd assume you were making the request from the computer where http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php is hosted from correct?

localhost means "this machine that i am making the request from right now" .

so unless your android machine has a web server running which has access to a file named /employee_details.php using localhost will not work from it.

Comment: HI, Instead of the URL "http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php "  If i give http://localhost/PHPMYSQL/index.php then its not working.

Comment: same rules apply, if /PHPMYSQL/index.php is not being served up locally by the android device you are executing your code on then you will not get results from that url.  From your recent comment I see you are running on an emulator. To access the dev machine from the emulator (the machine you are running the emulator from) use 10.0.2.2 as Noor has previously stated.

Comment: keep in mind though 10.0.2.2 will no longer work once you go to execute your code from an external android device.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your localhost machine with your machine IP address i.e `10.0.2.2`, and the port number which might be `80` OR `8080` and add it like this `http:// 10.0.2.2:8080/`

To find out your machine IP address use `ipconfig`

See [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) more details

**Update**

Add internet permission in `manifest.xml`, sometime its not resolve the issue then create another instance of `AVD`.

Comment: If i give IP Address instead of localhost and pasted in Google chrome then the below error is coming                                  Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /PHPMYSQL/index.php on this server.

Comment: Where you trying to hit your IP in emulator or your machine,  BTW manifest file has permission of INTERNET?

Comment: when i try "http://myip//PHPMYSQL/index.php"  I am getting the above errror.  And i am giving the same error in the exception if i give myip address

Comment: If i give http://localhost/PHPMYSQL/index.php,  then the below errors captured in Logcat.                                                                  12-29 23:33:13.011: E/AndroidRuntime(219): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-29 23:33:13.031: E/AndroidRuntime(219): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 23:33:13.031: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at org.json.JSONTokener.more(JSONTokener.java:98)
12-29 23:33:13.031: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at org.json.JSONTokener.next(JSONTokener.java:108)
12-29 23:33:13.031: E/AndroidRuntime(219):  at

Comment: My android setup                                                     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.phpmysql"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: Try to add internet permission in manifest like this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
`

Comment: Already it specified..
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code and steps with this :

http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12992/android-mysql-php-json-part-2-setting-up-a-xampp-server-and-mysql/